# how to use equalTo method in IOS program

Tags: ios, block, masonry

I have a question with iOS block ;

in `MASConstraint.h` ( a iOS third-party library )

have a method define :

```
- (MASConstraint * (^)(id attr))equalTo  ;
```

I cannot find the parameter with the method ,

but I can see many people use it with :

```
[subViews mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
}];
```

I don't understand it ,because I think the method (equalTo method) have not formal parameters.

but why the code `make.edges.equalTo(self.view)` is true ???

I need you help and thanks very mush .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(MASConstraint * (^)(id attr))equalTo` is a function pointer definition, the return value is MASConstraint, and it takes one parameter, which is a 'id' object, could represent any object type, called attr

So equalTo is variable, you could use it like a function, so for make.edges.equalTo(self.view), the parameter is self.view, and equalTo returns MASConstraint object

Comment: I know the equalTo method return (MASConstraint * (^)(id attr)) ,
but make.edges return MASConstraint *, 
so i think MASConstraint * (^ myBlock )(id attr)   =  make.edges.equalTo ;
myBlock(self.view) ;
 but why the code make.edges.equalTo(self.view)  is true ???

Comment: equalTo only return MASConstraint, not (MASConstraint * (^)(id attr))

Answer (score 0):

The method (`equalTo` method) do have formal parameters,it takes one parameter named `attr`, and the parameter  is a 'id' object.
As the format of block is very hard to remember,I personally like using this website (http://fuckingblocksyntax.com) to help me with the format of block. The name is easier to remember than the block syntax itself:

### http://fuckingblocksyntax.com

and if you can't load URLs with bad words in them you can use this mirror: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

[image: fuckingblocksyntax website]

### List of Block Declaration Syntaxes

Throughout, let

- `return_type` be the type of object/primitive/etc. you'd like to return (commonly `void`)
- `blockName` be the variable name of the block you're creating
- `var_type` be the type object/primitive/etc. you'd like to pass as an argument (leave blank for no parameters)
- `varName` be the variable name of the given parameter

And remember that you can create as many parameters as you'd like.

#### Blocks as Variables

Possibly the most common for of declaration.

```
return_type (^blockName)(var_type) = ^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    // ...
};
```

#### Blocks as Properties

Much like declaring blocks as variables, however subtly different.

```
@property (copy) return_type (^blockName) (var_type);
```

#### Blocks as Parameters

Note that this is distinct from "Blocks as Arguments"; in this instance, you're declaring a method that wants a block argument.

```
- (void)yourMethod:(return_type (^)(var_type))blockName;
```

#### Blocks as Arguments

Note that this is distinct from "Blocks as Parameters"; in this instance, you're calling a method that wants a block argument with an anonymous block. If you have already declared a block variable, it is sufficient to pass the variable name as the argument.

```
[someObject doSomethingWithBlock: ^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    //...
}];
```

#### Anonymous Block

This is functionally an anonymous block, however the syntax for assigning blocks to variables is simply to set the variable equal to an anonymous block.

```
^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    //...
};
```

#### `typedef` Block

This allows you to set up a short name that can be referenced just like any other class name during the declaration of blocks.

```
typedef return_type (^blockName)(var_type);
```

To then later use `blockName` instead of the standard block declaration syntax, simply substitute.

#### Inline Block

This is arguably a less useful utilization of blocks, but may have its place nonetheless. An inline block is an anonymous block called immediately after instantiation.

```
^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    //...
}(var);
```

Inline blocks are primarily useful for scope offsetting, and are roughly equivalent to simple brace-delimited chunks of code.

```
{
   //...
}
```

#### Recursive Blocks

This allows you to call a block from itself, creating a loop that can be used during callbacks and GCD calls. This instantiation method is free of retain cycles in ARC.

```
__block return_type (^blockName)(var_type) = [^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    if (returnCondition)
    {
        blockName = nil;
        return;
    }

    // ...
} copy];
blockName(varValue);
```

#### Returning Blocks

A method can return a block,

```
- (return_type(^)(var_type))methodName
{
    // ...
}
```

as can a function, if a bit strangely.

```
return_type (^FunctionName())(var_type)
{
    // ...
}
```

### Addendums

If I've missed anything, please let me know in comments, and I'll research/add them.

### Oh, and in Swift...

```
blockName = (varName: var_type) -> (return_type)
```

It's almost like it's a language feature.